# How to send Codeigniter CSRF token to angularjs data method

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

```
<input type="text" id="csrval" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
<input type="text" id="csname" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>">
```

I have set csrf name and token value in codeigniter view
Now I want to send these values to angularjs method

```
var tokenval = $('#csrval').val();
$rootScope.csrftokenval = tokenval;
var tokenname = $('#csname').val();
$rootScope.csrftokenname = tokenname;

//data: JSON.stringify({csrf_test_name:$rootScope.csrftokenval,page:page})
```

Not working for me ??
any solution ??

Answer (score 1):

Using only the first input, you can get the name and value attributes this way:

```
# Name
$("#csrval").attr('name');
# Value
$("#csrval").attr('value');
```